# Regex backreference not returning anything?

Tags: regex, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I'm new to regex, so please, bear with me.

I'm trying to replace everything that says `col-md-(\w+)` with `col-md-(\w+) col-lg-(\w+)` in Sublime Text 3.

However, when I use the line `col-md-\1 col-lg-\1`, it just turns into `col-md- col-xs-`

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

**Update:** Per request, I am showing the input/output:

[image]
[image]

...and when I replace all

[image]

Comment: What language? Show some context.

Comment: @M42 Sorry, I forgot to mention it in the question. I'm using the Find/Replace function in my editor, Sublime Text 3. I'll update the question.

Comment: Have you tried to use `$1`  instead of `\1`?

Comment: Can you past ome input

Comment: @vks I added images to help clarify.

Comment: Your find what has two groups and why is that lookahead there?

Comment: @vks The lookeahead is there because I have one of these things that is already set and does not need to be replaced.

http://i.imgur.com/Hawqz2m.png

Comment: @AvinashRaj Yes, and I also tried $1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove your lookahead and it will work :

```
Find What:    col-md-(\w+)
Replace With: col-xs-$1 col-sm-$1 col-md-$1 col-lg-$1
```

Or use `$2` instead of `$1`, as you've got a catching group inside this lookahead:

```
Find What:    (?!col-md-(\w+) )col-md-(\w+)
Replace With: col-xs-$2 col-sm-$2 col-md-$2 col-lg-$2
```

Comment: It's not useless, it's preventing col-md-'s with numbers after them (col-md-#) from being replaced.

Comment: Then use `$2` instead of `$1`, you've got a catching group **inside** your lookahead.

Comment: @AvinashRaj no technically zessx posted it in comments :P

Comment: @AvinashRaj It doesn't matter, you were both right.

Comment: @Dubstaphone can you try my find string and use `$1` and let me know if it works

Comment: @vks It didn't work for me. $2 is what I needed to use.

Comment: @Dubstaphone your regex is tecnically not correct.It is working but it is not correct.

Comment: @AvinashRaj i have changed the regex.See my ans

Comment: @AvinashRaj OP"s regex doesnt mame sense to me.

Comment: Gentlemen, you're making my phone crazy, ringing every 10 sec :)

Comment: @zessx yep, here also :-)

Answer (score 1):

OMG, you need to use `$2` instead of `$1`. Because of your negative lookahead already contains a capturing group, regex engine would refer to that group only if you use  `$1` in the replacement part. Use `$2` in the replacement part instead of `$1`, so that it would refer the group which was not inside the negative lookahead.

```
col-xs-$2 col-sm-$2 col-md-$2 col-lg-$2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
col-md-(\w+)(?!\s*col-lg)
```

Try this.This should resolve your problem.

Comment: Nope. Same problem. The find is working perfectly, but it's the replace that fails.

Comment: @Dubstaphone if you use this in find ,then does it work with `$1`?